# Summation of combination and permutation

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

$$\sum_{k=1}^{25}6\frac{^{24}P_{k-1}}{^{30}P_{k}}=1$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{25}6k\frac{^{24}P_{k-1}}{^{30}P_{k}}=\frac{31}{7}$$

This question come from a distribution. First equation is the sum of probability. Second equation is the expected value.

Is that any general way to calculate these two equation?

Comment: What more do you know about the context? Anything you know which can be helpful in solving this? Because this site isn't meant for direct homework questions and we can't provide direct solution.

Comment: I was a student of Applied Maths a decade ago, my job need to use a lot of maths, that why I still have a lot of reading now. This question come from a game, pick cards from 30 until you get a Game Over card. 24 cards with prize and 6 card to end the game. I used excel to calculate the mean number of cards that can collect, and also the probability of cards picked. I just wonder is that a general way that can calculate the equations, since i was a maths major  student, excel is just a calculator.